# RAII Multiple Constructor

Tags: c++, oop, raii

I just learned about RAII. From what I understand, the definition of RAII is in its name itself.For instance, (Let A be a class), consider the following function below:

```
void foo(){
   A a;
   a.init();
   // Do stuff with a.
   a.destroy();
}
```

Applaying RAII to the function above, we get:

```
void foo(){
  // Initializing the resource completely in a consttructor.
  A a;
  // Do stuff with a.
  // When out of scope, the destructor should be called.
}
```

So RAII is a good software development workflow since it reduces developer error since it takes advantage of constructor/destructor calls for resource initialization and deallocation.

**Problem:**

Suppose I have a class with multiple constructor, and contains data members that doesn't have a no-arg constructor to force RAII implementation. Consider the class below:

```
class A{
public:
  A(int arg1){
    int(arg1, GLOBAL_CONSTANT);
  }

  A(int arg1, arg2){
    init(arg1, arg2);
  }

  void init(int arg1, int arg2){
    _member = B(arg1, arg2);
  }

private:
  B _member;  // No-arg constructor member.
};
```

Since B also implements the RAII methodology, it doesn't have a no-arg constructor to force the user to not use an init() method later, thus _member must be initialized in a constructor list instead of **init**, making the the class above erroneous.

**Question:**

How do you exactly deal with this? What is the industry standard on dealing with this problem, if any at all?

I see the importance of RAII and don't want to compromise. Right now, the most clean solution in my head is have a single-constructor and use a factory method to generate variations. But I don't wanna rush and first takes into account experience of others, else I'll just create a nasty code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
A(int arg1, arg2) : _member(arg1, arg2) {}
```

In C++11, you can also have constructors call each other using [delegating constructors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement).

By the way, you should avoid using leading underscores on variable names as they are [reserved if followed by a capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).